# Compile Error from x86 that uses MOVAPS

Tags: gcc, x86, sse, simd, mmx

I'm getting a compile error of `Error: operand type mismatch for 'movaps'`, and googling hasn't revealed a solution. `movups` and `addps` also give the same error.

Here's a relevant excerpt:

```
# load address into %eax
movaps %eax, %mm0
```

For completeness, I'm compiling the `.s` file with `-m32`.

Comment: I don't think there's a 64 bit (MMX) version of `movaps`, so it probably needs to be `movaps %eax, %xmm0` ?

Comment: @KerrekSB I wasn't aware of this. (movapsd isn't recognized by gcc). I'm looking through Oracle's x86 reference manual now. @PaulR Adding the `x` didn't seem to help.

Comment: Are you trying to use old MMX (64 bit) vectors or is this supposed to be SSE (128 bits) ? Also, why asm, why not use intrinsics ?

Comment: Does the assignment specifically say you can't use intrinsics ? FWIW I looked at some gcc-generated asm and I see `movaps` instructions of the form `movaps (%ecx,%eax,4), %xmm0` - I'm not familiar with the syntax but I'm guessing that you may be missing a level of indirection on the first parameter.

Comment: @al92: Never mind, that was just a poor guess; I should have checked the manual. Deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a level of indirection on the first argument, and the second argument needs to be an XMM register (i.e. 128 bit SSE), not an MM register (old 64 bit MMX):

```
movaps (%eax), %xmm0
```

If you can use intrinsics in C or C++ rather than writing raw asm then you can do this kind of thing a lot more easily, e.g.

```
__m128 v = _mm_load_ps(ptr);
```

Comment: Thanks! I was missing the () too.